# Extension OAuth not showing in php.ini in php 7.4 and Class 'OAuth' not found

Tags: php, oauth, php-7.4

I have OAuth installed locally. Command php -m showing OAuth. But phpinfo() noth showing anything about OAuth, and project that i'm working with prompts error Class 'OAuth' not found on line where this class is created.
[image]
[image]